# generate hibernate dao and ddl with maven plugin

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

I am setting up a project that uses hibernate, and I am writing the classes and adding annotations to avoid writing .hbm.xml files. I am also trying to use maven hibernate3 plugin specifically hbm2dao and hbm2ddl for dao and database creation but I get the error

`failed: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class=package.ClassName.....`

hibernate.cfg.xml follows:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="jndi/composite/SessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">PASS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/DATABASE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">USER</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory    </property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
        <mapping class="package.....models.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

configuration for the plugin on pom.xml

```
<configuration>
    <components>            
        <component>
            <name>hbm2dao</name>
            <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/hibernate3</outputDirectory>
        </component>
    </components>
    <componentProperties>
        <jdk5>true</jdk5>
        <ejb3>false</ejb3>
        <packagename>package......models</packagename>
        <format>true</format>
        <haltonerror>true</haltonerror>
        <scan-classes>true</scan-classes>
    </componentProperties>
</configuration>
```

Any info that I may be forgetting just ask, thanks.

Comment: Does your error end with 'Unable to load class declared as'?

Comment: I didnt format it properly sorry, should be visible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found a solution to my problem, my main issue is that when using classes on the hibernate.cfg.xml it will use the compiled classes, and not the sources as I was thinking anyway here is how I solved it.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile-hibernate-classes</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>FILTER_TO_INCLUDE_HIBERNATE_CLASSES</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>compile-all</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>    

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>hbm2dao</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>hbm2dao</name>
                <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/hibernate3</outputDirectory>
            </component>
            <component>
                <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/hibernate3</outputDirectory>
            </component>
        </components>
        <componentProperties>
            <jdk5>true</jdk5>
            <ejb3>false</ejb3>
            <packagename>PACKAGE_GOES_HERE</packagename>
            <haltonerror>true</haltonerror>
        </componentProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So the first execution of the compiler plugin will compile just the classes needed to generate the dao classes, and the second to compile everything.
The execution on the hibernate plugin will make sure the dao classes are generated when compiling.

May not be the best way but works for me.