# Useing hibernate reverse engineering with hibernate-spatial, postgis and custom nameing strategy

Tags: java, maven, postgis, hibernate-tools, hibernate-spatial

I'm searching for an example to use hibernate reverse engineering for an existing postgis database (http://code.google.com/p/indicia/) for usage with hibernate-spatial and a custom naming strategy (because tables are plural with underscores in the database).

It would be great if someone could provide a working maven example, since I seem to be lost in version conflicts from hibernate-tool maven plugin and hibernate-spatial. Also I have not found any solution for adding a naming strategy to the maven plugin.

Regards

Daniel

**UPDATE**

I've managed what I wanted. The result is tow maven artifacts: one with the naming strategy and one with the generated classes.

The pom.xml for the nameing strategy has just tow dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.GA</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernatespatial</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial-postgis</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The other pom.xml adds this artifact to the plugin dependencies

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864778/generate-hibernate-dao-and-ddl-with-maven-plugin